# Correct method to bind an entity as children of an NSTreeController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, binding, nstreecontroller

Am I correct in my understanding of how to populate an `NSOutlineview` with an `NSTreeController` who is bound to two seperate entities that have a relationship between them:

My `NSTreeController` has a managedObjectContext bound to my `appDelegate`. My `Object Controller` for this  is an entity named **clients**. My `NSOutlineViews` `tableColumn` is bound to the `NSTreeController` (and **clients**) `key path` **clientCompany** and this populates my `NSOutlineView` correctly with a list of company names.

My second entity, **projects**, has a relationship property called **projectParent** inverse-bound to a property in clients called **clientChild**. Through this relationship, I want the children of my `NSTreeController` to be made up of the relevant **projects** entries that have the relevant **clientCompany** as a parent.

To attempt this, I made **clientChild** the `children` `key path` in my `NSTreeController` and then bound my `content set` of the same controller to the **clientChild** `key path` of my **clients** entity with the `Controller Key` as 'selected'.

This method and various combinations don't seem to work and produce varying errors. It's only if I leave out that last '`content set`' binding step that the program runs without errors on startup and has open/close icons next to the the outlineview entries, suggesting it populated like I wanted. On trying to open one of the entries, it produces an error suggesting my **projects** entity isn't KVC compliant with my **clientChild** property. I've gone over and over the bindings and can't seem to find the problem.

Comment: Just to add: I see where I may be going wrong with the fact that I haven't defined what property of projects I want to be listed in the outlineview as a child. I tried defining it as clientChild.projectTitle in children but this didn't remove the errors.

Comment: I'm still in progress on this but I've been going down the route of avoid NSTreeController and attempting to programmatically make my own datasource and delegate to combine the 2 existing entities into linked nodes in an outlineview.

I'm still surprised there isn't an easier way to do this. It seems silly that IB has all of its binding features but can't make a bound NSOutlineView of parents and children using existing entities that contain parent and children relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From over a weeks worth of reading and researching, I believe the answer is that this isn't possible. This surprises me a little - considering all the time saver shortcuts that Interface Builder and NSTreeController provide, I thought my situation was common enough that this would have been implemented in Interface Builder or a built-in class.

I'm not in the process of creating my own class to do what I want and hopefully this answer is useful to anybody who was searching for this and couldn't find many answers (google wasn't much use).